# CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: android, linux, jenkins, build, automation

I have set `$ANDROID_HOME` and `$PATH` to my jenkins user in `bash_profile`(in my case it's the admin user) and I can see `env` var fetches values when I do

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME 
echo $PATH
```

But when I do

```
sudo cordova build android
```

it gives me the error

> CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable.Try setting it manually. Try update your 'PATH'

Any idea why and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a command using `sudo` the command doesn't inherit environment variables from the parent (unprivileged) shell.  For security reasons.

Solutions:

- Use `sudo bash` to start a root shell.  Then set the environment variables and run your build command in the root shell.
- Use `sudo -E ...` or `sudo --preserve-env=...` but read the manual entry because this is risky.
- Don't try to run cordova as root. (Why are you doing that? It seems risky.  Can you be sure that your build doesn't have bugs that might damage your system if run as root?  Can you trust the source of the build "scripts"?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. My issue was fixed by adding below command. 
sudo ANDROID_HOME="/home/opc/androidsdk" PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH" PATH="$PATH:/home/opc/gradle/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin" cordova build android --release --nofetch >>> in my jenkins config portal